# Can't interact with github

Tags: linux, git, github

My laptop runs arch linux. I wanted to use github to backup my project. In the beginning everything worked fine, I was able to push the first two commits. 
Then I wanted to push the third commit but it took forever. From then on every communication (push, pull, clone etc. on multiple repositories) with the remote repository took forever and ended with the error: `fatal: could not read from remote repository`. There was one exception where i was able to push. Afterwards it was the same again.

The ssh authentication is working. `ssh git@github.com` delivers the expected response. 
 (`ssh -T git@github.com` takes forever and is not successful  - is this relevant?)

There are a few similar threads but I haven't found a working answer.

What i have already tried:

- Checked remote repository (`git remote -v`): -- is correct
- Started ssh-agent and added key (`` eval `ssh-agent`, ssh-add ``)
- Forcing ssh to use IPv4 (in  `~/.ssh/config`: `AddressFamily inet`)
- Removed git enviroment variable (`unset GIT_SSH`)
- Tried multiple keys (rsa, ed25519) with/without password
- Used the url wiht `ssh://` scheme (`ssh://git@yourhost:port/path/repo.git`)
- Updated git
- Complete update of the os
- Credential helper disabled (`git config --global --unset credential.helper`)
- Checked credentials (`git config --global user.name` , `git config --global user.email`)

I even tried to trace the git pull:

> `GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 git push -u origin main --verbose`

With the result:

```
14:10:30.980851 trace.c:312             setup: git_common_dir: .git
14:10:30.980857 trace.c:313             setup: worktree: /home/alex/Entwicklung/NetCore/ActivityTrackerPC
14:10:30.980863 trace.c:314             setup: cwd: /home/alex/Entwicklung/NetCore/ActivityTrackerPC
14:10:30.980868 trace.c:315             setup: prefix: (null)
14:10:30.980872 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git push -u origin main --verbose
Push nach github.com:2kHammer/ActivityTracker.git
14:10:30.984208 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh git@github.com 'git-receive-pack '\''2kHammer/ActivityTracker.git'\'''
```

Then it hangs until the error occures.

For now i copied the project to my raspberry und pushed from there. There it worked without problems.

I am really desperate, git is an essential tool.

Comment: Just so you know, [`user.name` is a personal name, not a username, and is unrelated to authentication](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name).

Comment: The "takes forever" thing probably *is* relevant, although exactly how is a mystery. Use a tool like tcpdump or wireshark to monitor the actual network traffic, and compare the slow but successful `ssh -T git@github.com` with the unsuccessful `git push`. Check for middleware / proxy boxes that may be corrupting data, etc. If a pattern emerges, that will help you find the culprit.

Comment: It's also worth dumping the packet trace both from the Linux box, and from some other box that can see it (another laptop for instance where you can put the Ethernet hardware into snoop mode). Sometimes problems like this wind up being due to bugs in the device drivers, such that some packets get corrupted. Hardware checksums and [TSO and so on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine) contribute to these things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re add your ssh key to your ssh agent

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id
```

where id is the ssh key is the key associated with your github repository

Comment: I have tried this multiple times. Most of the time I had only one key pair. ```ssh-add``` has automatically added the correct key to ssh-agent.